# How to navigate back to a pseudo url, created using pushState, from an external webpage?

Tags: javascript, back-button, pushstate, html5-history

Trying to understand the history API, the Mozilla explanation below suggests to me that even if the url you push to the history does not really exist on the server, a back button click from an external source will return the original page from which the pushState call was made:

> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

> This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.
>
> Suppose now that the user now navigates to google.com, then clicks back. At this point, the URL bar will display ...mozilla.org/bar.html, and the page will get a popstate event whose state object contains a copy of stateObj. The page itself will look like foo.html, although the page might modify its contents during the popstate event.
>
> If we click back again, the URL will change to ...mozilla.org/foo.html, and the document will get another popstate event, this time with a null state object. Here too, going back doesn't change the document's contents from what they were in the previous step, although the document might update its contents manually upon receiving the popstate event.

I have created a test page in an MVC project that literally just associates a button click with the 2 lines of javascript from the above example. Clicking the button, as expected, changes the browser location from localhost to localhost/bar.html, and the back and forward buttons work as expected. But if I then navigate to google and press the back button, I get a 404 server error. Have I misunderstood the documentation? And how can I ammend the code so that a back button from an external source works, without creating an actual 'bar.html'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else is wondering about the same thing, I'm now using query strings appended to my real url rather than non-existent paths to push to history. This achieves what I wanted, i.e. I can push states, navigate to an external page, then hit the back button and retrieve the state by listening for a popstate.

(Admittedly I am still slightly confused by the Mozilla documentation which does suggest (to me at least!) that a fake path should work.)

Comment: I'm playing around with the same code from MDN, using `foo` and `bar` for my URLs after the / and have the back and forward working, but I get a 404 when I tried and browse directly to a url like `/foo`. It seems like at that point I would need an .htaccess or redirect to handle the URL, where a `/#foo` would get the index file and then I could act on the hash. I'm also still confused on just how to use the history as a direct link.

Comment: After a bit more research and looking at a nice [example on Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), it seems like you either need query strings or actual files. There's a link for an html5 [demo page](http://html5demos.com/history), where if you try to browse directly to one of the [pushState pages](http://html5demos.com/history/second) in a new widow you get a not found just like we're having.

Comment: Yeah, some of the documentation is a bit misleading/ambiguous I think; query strings or actual files definitely needed!

Comment: @kaplan, late reply but still worth it. For a direct link, indeed if you have a single page application, you need to set up your web server so that any request that is not an asset responds with your index page. This is the basic setup for an SPA. The reason why it work with the fragment (e.g. #bla-balh) is because the fragment is purely a browser thing. The web server does not receive it at all. Your browser and JS can access it, but as far as the server is concerned, it is asked the page without it. That's why apart from uglier URLs, the fragment trick is so convenient.

Answer (score 1):

pushstate is half of the equation....

You also need to listen for popstate:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {

    console.log(arguments)
    // read the arguments to figure out what state you need return to
    // change the page to however you need 

});
```

Add this function above and watch the console.  What I do is save enough information in js variables so I can set the page as needed.

pushstate and popstate are very useful in html5 mobile development when you're creating a "single page web app".  This is exactly how I use it and it works great.

Comment: Thanks, but my issue is prior to setting the page. A back button click from google, say, to my localhost/bar.html gives a 404 file not found error. It is not loading anything at all.